# Get winform Webbrowsercontrol Source from app config file

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, app-config

Can someone please show me how to get winforms Webbrowsercontrol source from appconfig file ?.

I tried with following but it's not working

```
webBrowser2.Navigate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dateandtime"];
```

and this is my how app config file look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <add key="serverip" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <add key="dbport" value="3306" />
    <add key="defdatabase" value="waq115" />
    <add key="dateandtime" value="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4daxch9/n77/fs18/fcfff/tc212426/pc212426" />
</appSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I'm really sorry I edited my question with what I have already tried sir

Comment: I edited my question with all the details can you please look in to it ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate() is a method ***not*** a variable, So the following line of code will not compile,

```
webBrowser2.Navigate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dateandtime"];
```

You have to read the URL from the application configuration file and pass it as an argument to Navigate("URL") method as follows.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dateandtime"]);
```

Comment: thanks sir but it's not working I want to load that webpage when form load event but when I get this URLfrom app config file it's not working. but when I insert URL directly from properties it was working

Comment: now its working I mistakenly set the incomplete URL  thank you so much